# how can we find the syllables for hindi text using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a hindi text like this "यह है मोटा राजा।  मोटे राजा का है दुबला कुत्ता। मोटा राजा व दुबला कुत्ता घूमने निकले।  दुबले कुत्ते ने चिड़िया देखी। वह उसके पीछे भागा।  मोटा राजा दुबले कुत्ते के पीछे भागा।  दोनों भागे। और कई दिनों तक भागते रहे!  मोटे राजा ने दुबले कुत्ते को पकड़ ही लिया।  मोटा राजा अब दुबला है!" now, I want to find all the syllables in this text.please can anyone suggest me

Comment: Did you try *anything* before posting the question?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got syllables by defining a function using the unicodes of vowels, consonants etc., of the Hindi language.